# Подбор чисел из массива определенной суммы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, имеется задача: Из массива чисел выбрать любое кол - во элементов, которые в сумме дадут заданное число.При этом одно и тоже число не может быть использовано 2 раза.Я хочу послушать, как Вы бы решили эту задачу.Понятно, что это одна из вариаций задачи о рюкзаке, да и судя по всему задача относится к NP.

Comment: Рюкзак и есть, в чистом виде.

Comment: Вроде бы классическая задача о рюкзаке проще, ибо там можно брать один и тот же предмет неограниченное число раз, буду благодарен за любую ссылку, связанную с моей проблемой.